# Deploy qt application with all its dependencies

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I developed a QT application on ubunty linux. I want to include dependencies in my deployed file so that my application can works in any other machine running with ubuntu.

Comment: Start here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html and post more detailed questions if any

Comment: Thanks I will try this

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is to distribute your application as a `.dpkg` so the dependencies can be automatically installed. Including dependencies in the binary is tricky and generally means statically compiling libraries instead of dynamically linking them but even then you run into problems.

Comment: The problem is that the destination machine dosn't have internet

Comment: I haven't tried it, but [dpkg-offline](https://launchpad.net/dpkg-offline/) seems to be able to download the dependencies and package them so that they can be distributed to a machine without internet connection.